# How can I check the content of number of divs with the same ID, and add a class to those that contain a certain piece of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

e.g. For the below, how would I add the class `.out-of-stock` and remove the text "nostock" from the first and third divs:

```
<div id="variant">Blue nostock</div>
<div id="variant">Red</div>
<div id="variant">Yellow nostock</div>
<div id="variant">Green</div>
```

I tried, the following to add the class, but it didn't work:

```
$('#variant:contains("nostock")').addClass('out-of-stock');
```

Thanks

Comment: ID's have to be unique, you can't have the same ID more than once. Use classes instead.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yurzui/oa46h32u/)

Comment: Use `<div id="variant1" class="variant">Blue nostock</div>` and `$('.variant:contains("nostock")').addClass('out-of-stock');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a class instead of `id` as id ***must*** be unique for each element. from:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element ...

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/3ofckc9u/2/)

```js
$('.variant').each(function() {
  var theHTML = $(this).html();
  
  // if it contains nostock
  if (theHTML.indexOf('nostock') > -1) {
    $(this).addClass('out-of-stock');
  }
});
```

```css
.out-of-stock{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variant">Blue nostock</div>
<div class="variant">Red</div>
<div class="variant">Yellow nostock</div>
<div class="variant">Green</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. Is there a line I could add to remove the "nostock" text from the div too? I will style the div to show it's out of stock, so the extra text isn't really required.

Comment: @Ben you welcome, and sure we can filter out the "nostock" by making use of `.replace()` function then re-inject the new content into the element html using `.html()` as this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/3ofckc9u/4/)

Comment: I'm glad it helped, enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you control the way `div`s are generated, you can easily append a `nostock` class to each element which has `nostock` in text:

```
<div id="variant" class="nostock">Blue nostock</div>
<div id="variant">Red</div>
<div id="variant" class="nostock">Yellow nostock</div>
<div id="variant">Green</div>
```

Your `jQuery` is much easier to do now:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var noStockLen = "nostock".length + 1;
        $(".nostock").each(function (index, value) {
            value.innerText = value.innerText.substring(0, value.innerText.length - noStockLen);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I only have control of the content of the divs. But I was able to add a class to all of them, and solved using a solution like Mi-Creativity and Nenad Vracar suggested.

Answer (score 0):

An id must be unique.
You should use another attribute instead.

```
<div name="variant">Blue nostock</div>
<div name="variant">Red</div>
<div name="variant">Yellow nostock</div>
<div name="variant">Green</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[name="variant"]:contains("nostock")').addClass('out-of-stock');
</script>
```

Comment: why not a just a class ?

Comment: It's another option. Both are valid.

Comment: But I would prefer not to add a class if it has no use in the CSS.

Comment: i agree, it is just more 'usual' practice ;)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to add a class to all the div s and used the solution from Mi-Creativity above.